# Automatically format cents (in currency) with Regex having unknown cent digit total count

Tags: javascript

I had done some Google search and found it to be more difficult not knowing what the proper keyword to search for.

What I'm looking for in JavaScript is to auto populate the cents.  Example here are.

1) If no cents then leave as dollar amount.
2) If a dot is entered then auto populate the .00
3) If 1 digit cents is found then auto populate the 2nd cent digit
4) If 2 digit cents is found then do nothing.

Doing this in all-in-one bulk RegExp.replace() algorithm?

Comment: So you'd need to match `\.$` and `\.\d$` and replace as appropriate.

Comment: You should check like `value = value.replace('.', 'x');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```js
    
    function autocomplete(input) {
        var output = input.replace(/(\d*\.)$/,"$100").replace(/(\d*\.\d)$/,"$10");
        return output;
    }
    
    console.log(autocomplete("10"));
    console.log(autocomplete("10."));
    console.log(autocomplete("10.1"));
    console.log(autocomplete("10.12"));
```